# In a nuget init.ps1 how do you detect if running as install or as console initialization

Tags: powershell, nuget

So init.ps1 https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal  runs in two circumstance. When you install a package for the first time and when you open the nuget powershell console as part of opening a solution.

> Init.ps1 runs the first time a package is installed in a solution.... The script also runs every time the solution is opened

So inside Init.ps1 how do you determine in which context it is running?

Comment: I'd guess setting an environment variable the PowerShell script will read to determine which context to use.  Without examples, it's really anyones guess.

Comment: @user4317867 "Without examples, it's really anyones guess" i dont understand this?

Comment: @user4317867 " setting an environment variable the PowerShell script will read to determine which context to use" how would this with the same script runs in both contexts where would i set the variable?

Comment: The first line of `init.ps1` is `param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)` meaning when the `init.ps1` is called, you pass the params by doing `init.ps1 -installPath <YourAnswer> -TOOLSPath <YourAnswer2>` and so on.  Thus, when you call init.ps1, you pass it the required params.  See [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/19/writing-a-nuget-package-that-adds-a-command-to-the.aspx/) for details

Comment: @user4317867 i dont call that method. it is called from nuget. i cant pass it custom parameters. from the link u gave "These are the parameters that NuGet will pass into the init.ps1 script"

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a built-in way—`Init.ps1` is meant to be called each time Package Manager Console is initialized, so there's purposefully no context parameter. As Yishai Galatzer puts it in no uncertain terms [on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2428#issuecomment-204163098):

> That's not the intent of init.ps1, and we will not enable it. NuGet is not an automation entry point into visual studio, and please do not use it as such.

I do find this a bit unfortunate since support for `Install.ps1` and `Uninstall.ps1` was [removed in NuGet 3](http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html#powershell-install-and-uninstall-scripts) back in 2015, which means we can no longer run custom code after installation, even simple stuff like showing an HTML readme. The reasoning makes sense, but it would be nice if there were an alternative for package installs specifically inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

It's old question but maybe it helps somebody. To run script during package installation instead of console initialization put your code inside **install.ps1** file.

Comment: [`Install.ps1` was deprecated in NuGet v3](http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html#powershell-install-and-uninstall-scripts) and unfortunately there's no longer an equivalent. See my answer.